# Mysql searching with different sort order with each sublevel

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want searching with different sort order with each sublevel
like

```
Group A
      Sub Group A ( ASC )
           Trans#1
           Trans#2
           Trans#3
      Sub Group B ( DESC )
           Trans#3
           Trans#2
           Trans#1
Group B
      Sub Group A ( custom )
           Trans#2
           Trans#1
           Trans#3
      Sub Group B ( custom )
           Trans#3
           Trans#1
           Trans#2
      Sub Group E ( DESC )
           Trans#3
           Trans#2
           Trans#1
```

Can we do this type of hierarchy sorting order by in MYSQL?

Comment: Did my answer help you achieve the desired result? How is it going?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `UNION ALL` could help you?

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM ...
ORDER BY ... (some criterion)
UNION ALL
SELECT a, b, c FROM ...
ORDER BY ... (some other criterion)
UNION ALL
SELECT...
```

and so on. So basically the idea is, write a query for each subgroup with the desired `ORDER BY` clause, and then union them using `UNION ALL` in between SELECTs.

Comment: Thanks I will try with this'